# @Query behaves differently when searching TemplateRef

Tags: angular

To begin with this behavior only happens in beta16, previous releases are working as expected.

@Query also finds the template elements of descendant elements, consider a component looking for Template elements in content;

```
export class Container {

    constructor(@Query(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef>) {
        templates.changes.subscribe(_ => {
            console.log(templates.length);
        });
    }

}

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<container>
             <template></template>
             <child>
                 <template></template>
             </child>
           </container>`,
directives: [Container,Child]
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sANW6mfss5EvPfWpXRde

I expect "1" to be logged on console, but "2" is logged. Template of child is also found.

But replacing template element with some random component e.g. otherchild, produces the expected result;

```
export class Container {

    constructor(@Query(OtherChild) templates: QueryList<OtherChild>) {
        templates.changes.subscribe(_ => {
            console.log(templates.length);
        });
    }

}


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<container>
             <otherchild></otherchild>
             <child>
                 <otherchild></otherchild>
             </child>
           </container>`,
directives: [Container,Child,OtherChild]
```

})

http://plnkr.co/edit/OzXjz8niAurzr6CZIoes

"1" is printed as container has only one otherchild.

So something is different with template elements causing confusion. I wonder if this is a bug or intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`@Query()` which is deprecated since a while in favor of [`@ContentChildren()`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ContentChildren-var.html).

Hint: the result of `@ContentChildren()` can't be accessed in the constructor, only after `ngAfterContentInit()` was called.

Also `descendants: true` needs to be passed to not only get direct children but all descendants (this might be what has changed the `@Query()` - I don't know if this parameter is now available there as well)

```
export class Container {
  @ContentChildren(OtherChild, {descendants: true}) templates;
  ngAfterContentInit( ) {
    console.log(this.templates.length);
    this.templates.changes.subscribe(_ => {
      console.log(templates.length);
    });
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuavFKpKE02thLzj8rgd?p=preview)

I can reproduce your issue with `@ContentChildren()` as well. This code also prints **2** but it should print **1**. I assume this is a bug caused by the change to `@ContentChilren()` and `@ViewChildren()` in beta.16.

```
export class Container {
  @ContentChildren(TemplateRef, {descendants: false}) templates;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.templates.length);
    this.templates.changes.subscribe(_ => {
      console.log(templates.length);
    });
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EI1Qbgppi3sLCeYBfTyl?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it doesn't happen in beta15 also only applies when looking for template element, any other component like otherchild in my second plunkr works as expected. I've filed this issue already; https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8292